# Cron not running shell program stored on desktop

Tags: python, shell, cron, python-requests, cron-task

I am trying to run a shell (.sh file) program that will then run a python script making requests from a website. The python program outputs a file containing json data to my desktop and I would like this to run at 10AM Monday-Friday.

This is my .sh shell file. It runs correctly when executed manually from from terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
python tester.py
```

This is what I have been using to test the shell. This would run every minute and produce my output file but it is not working:

```
* * * * * /path/to/file/test.sh && ./test.sh
```

I have tried a couple other syntax combinations as follows:

```
* * * * * sh /path/to/file 
* * * * * sh /path/to/file/test.sh && sh test.sh
```

I am aware the correct notation for a program running at 10am mon-fri would be:

```
0 10 * * 1-5
```

Nothing seems to be working and I am at a complete loss.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if in the script file you add these two lines: `DISPLAY=:0` and `export DISPLAY` before calling python?

Comment: @Roadowl Still not working.. I have a feeling the problem has something to do with my path. This is my cron command I am trying..

Comment: * * * * * /User/username/Desktop/test.sh && ./test.sh

Comment: the test.sh file is stored on my desktop could this have something to do with it? I am new to programming and this is my first attempt with cron.

Comment: maybe use `echo text > /full/path/file.txt` in shell script  to see which line is executed. And maybe you should use `/full/path/python /full/path/tester.py`. And maybe you should use full path instead of `./` in `./test.sh`. And maybe you should create script with `/path/to/file/test.sh && ./test.sh` and this script use in cron. BTW: if you save data in `tester.py` then also use `/full/path/file.json`

Comment: frankly, I don't understand why you use `&&` and `/path/to/file/test.sh && ./test.sh`. Maybe you should use directly `/full/path/python /full/path/tester.py` in cron. And if it display some data on screen then you can redirect to file `/full/path/python /full/path/tester.py > /full/path/output.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being my cron did not have full disk access. I was able to change this in

Answer (score 0):

Just use a line for /path/to/file/test.sh in the crontab.  As furas mentioned in their comment you shouldn't need to use the &&. It shouldn't matter if the script is on your desktop if the path is correct.  You can also check the syslog to see if there are any errors.